# Struggling with installing Audacious, which requires pkg-config

Tags: unix, cygwin, pkg-config

Title should be self-explanatory. I thought the pkg_config installation didn't give me errors at all, so I assumed it installed fine, but I got this error when installing Audacious.

How do I deal with path to make sure that pkg_config is set up correctly?

```
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.
```

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions, Superuser maybe.

Comment: what is the output of `cygcheck -c pkg-config` ?

Comment: Only seems to show`Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
`
Guess it wasn't properly installed then??